# Vagrant: running ansible provisioning just while creating virtual machine?

Tags: vagrant, provisioning, ansible

Using Vagrant, is it possible to run my provisioning Ansible script just when vagrant up creates the virtual machine? I  wan to provision just when the import sequence is run. I have a very slow step that imports the database. It isn't  idempotent and I'd like it to run just the first time.

I can make a script using `vagrant status` and `vagrant up --no-provision`, but I believe there should be a more straightforward  way.

I also can just run Ansible after the first vagrant up, but then I won't be able to brag to my friends that I create my server from scratch running just one command :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are using a version older than 1.3.0;-)

Since Vagrant 1.3.0, `vagrant up` only run provisioning **by default the first time it runs (after the import)**. Subsequent reload or up will need to explicitly specify the `--provision` flag, for example `vagrant up --provision` or just `vagrant provision`.

See the full [changelog](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

The change => vagrant up will now only run provisioning by default the first time it is run. Subsequent reload or up will need to explicitly specify the --provision flag to provision. [GH-1776]

Comment: Great! I'm using the Ubuntu default version. I'll update it now.